# Can I shave exposed roots from a Silver Maple tree to avoid damage when mowing?

Tags: trees, roots, maple, mowing

We have large roots from a huge [Silver Maple](http://www.mortonarb.org/trees-plants/tree-plant-descriptions/silver-maple) tree that are partially above ground and interfere with mowing.

Can I shave them so the mower can pass over them?

Answer (score 10):

No, you shouldn't interfere with them or damage them in any way, you may compromise the tree if you do. If possible, remove the grass that's near the roots, plant ground cover instead or just mulch around the roots.

Answer (score 6):

Far better to mulch the area or otherwise remove it from mowing. A huge tree is a huge issue when it's in trouble, and cutting roots is very likely to cause trouble, as the tree depends on the supplies from those roots, their physical support, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I would not do that, shaving off the roots can really hurt or even kill the tree. I would just go around the root then come back with scissors and cut around the root. You could also use a weed wacker to get close but try not to hit the root. It will not do much to the root but it could break you string on the weed wacker. Then get were you need to go with the scissors.